# why child class can access object while parent can't

Tags: unity, collision-detection, inheritance

I have Block class which is the parent and StandardBlock the child , the prefab block have StandardBlock script attached to it, and according to my small knowledge in inheriting I though this would work

```
public class Block : MonoBehaviour
{
HUD HUDscript;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    HUDscript = GameObject.FindWithTag("Canvas").GetComponent<HUD>();  
}
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    HUDscript.addPoints();
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
}
```

and child class

```
public class StandardBlock : Block
 {

      // some code
}
```

but this is the error that i got

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Block.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D col) (at Assets/Scripts/Gameplay/Block.cs:24)

while writing `OnCollisionEnter2D` in the child class worked fine

Comment: Did you write a new Start method in your child class?

Comment: @DMGregory yes I did , so now I can see the problem, I didn't write base.start() in child start method, now it's working fine. Thank you a lot

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please write up your solution as an Answer. :) You'll be able to mark it as Accepted after a short delay, and other users can up-vote it if they find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I used a start method too in the child class I should have written it that way

```
override protected void Start()
{
    //some code
    base.Start();
}
```

and in the parent class

```
virtual protected void Start()
{
    HUDscript = GameObject.FindWithTag("Canvas").GetComponent<HUD>();


}
```

so now the child can implement both methods

Thanks to @DMGregory